# Confused with implicit pointer dereference when assigning a pointer to interface in Go

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I am new to Go, and I am studying its interface feature.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
)

type Integer int

func (a Integer) Less(b Integer) bool {
        return a < b
}

func (a *Integer) Add(b Integer) {
        *a += b
}

type LessAdder interface {
        Less(b Integer) bool
        Add(b Integer)
}

var a Integer = 1

var b LessAdder = &a

func main() {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))
        fmt.Println(b.Less(2))
        b.Add(a)
        fmt.Println(a)

}
```

And it will output the the following:

```
*main.Integer
true
2
```

Well, this works pretty well.

The Point is:
How `var b LessAdder = &a` works. Does the pointer auto-dereference happens right here, or when b invokes member method?

The output `*main.Integer` tells us that b is a pointer to type `Integer`, hence it is the second case.

Then the tricky thing comes:
when I add `fmt.Pringln(*b)` to the code, the compiler comes with an error:

```
 demo/demo1
./demo1.go:31: invalid indirect of b (type LessAdder)
```

And it confuses me. **Since `b` is a pointer type to `Integer`, then dereferencing it should work. But why not?**

Comment: In addition to what icza stated: Interface are **types** in Go, they are *not* syntactical sugar or magical wrappers. An interface type has the same status as builtin types like int32 or a user defined struct.

Answer (score 11):

Your last sentence:

> **"Since `b` is a pointer type to `Integer`, then dereferencing it should work."**

Stop right there. `b` is **not** a variable of pointer type and therefore you can't [dereference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) it.

It is a variable of [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) which is schematically a pair of a value and a type (value,type), holding `&a` as the value and `*Integer` as the type (blog article [The Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection), section [The representation of an interface](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.)).

This is a declaration of a variable of pointer type, `*Integer`:

```
var ip *Integer
```

And this is one of an interface type:

```
var intf LessAdder
```

When you do this:

```
var b LessAdder = &a
```

What happens is that an interface value (of type `LessAdder`) is created automatically/implicitly which will hold the value `&a` (and the type `*Integer`). This is a valid operation because the type of `&a` (which is `*Integer`) implements the interface `LessAdder`: the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of `*Integer` is a superset of the interface `LessAdder` (in this case they are equal, the method set of an interface type is its interface).

Now when you call `b.Less(2)`, since `Less()` has a value receiver, the pointer will be dereferenced and a copy of the pointed value will be made and used/passed as the value receiver of the method `Less()`.

`fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))` doesn't lie, but it will print the *dynamic* type of `b`. The dynamic type of `b` is indeed `*Integer`, but the *static* type of `b` is `LessAdder` and the static type is what determines what you can do with a value and what operators or methods are allowed on it.

Comment: So `b` is a type of `Interface{&a, *Integer}` , and *Interface* is a type of types?

Comment: @LeckieNi Schematically, yes. But what happens is that an interface value is created automatically/implicitly holding the pair `(&a, *Integer)` and this interface value is assigned to `b`. See edited answer.

Comment: And then `b` calls `b.Less(2)`, it is actually calling `(&a).Less(2)`. And here 's where auto-dereference happens?

Comment: @LeckieNi `b` holds a pointer value, of type `*Integer`. Since `Less()` has value receiver, this pointer will be dereferenced, and a copy of the pointed value will be made and used/passed as the value receiver of the method. Since `b` holds a pointer that is `&a`, the value of `a` will be used. See edited answer.

Comment: So, output of fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b)) is lying and printing wrong type?

Comment: @MarkoKevac No, `fmt.Println()` doesn't lie, but it will print the _dynamic_ type of `b`. The dynamic type of `b` is indeed `*Integer`, but the _static_ type of `b` is `LessAdder` and the static type is what determines what you can do with a value and what operators or methods are allowed on it. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

`LessAdder` is declared as an interface with the methods `Less` and `Add`. Since `Add` is declared with a receiver of `*Integer`, a `*Integer` can be a `LessAdder`; an `Integer` can't. When you do `var b LessAdder = &a`, it's the pointer to `a` that's stored in the interface `b`.

The automatic indirection occurs at the call to `b.Less(2)`, because both methods on `*Integer` and methods on `Integer` contribute to the method set of `*Integer`.

You can't use `*b` because although `b` *contains* a `*Integer`, statically its type is `LessAdder`, not `*Integer`. Leaving aside the representation of interfaces, `LessAdder` isn't a pointer type, and `*b`, if it was allowed, would have no expressible type at all.

You can use a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to access `b` as an `Integer *` again; `b.(*Integer)` is an expression of type `*Integer`, and `*b.(*Integer)` is an `Integer`. Both of these will run-time panic if the value in `b` is not a `*Integer` after all.